# Is it better to store data in multiple columns or serialzed objects in sql?

Tags: sql, database-design, serialization

I am designing a database to track events on a site. One of my tables stores Server and Session variables associated with the event, I'm looking to see what is the best solution for storing this data.

### **Solution 1**

*Each Variable is a column in the table*

---

```
 ID | APPL_MD_PATH | APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH | AUTH_TYPE | AUTH_USER | ETC...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | /ROOT/       | \localhost\        |NULL       |NULL       |NULL
 2  | /ROOT/       | \localhost\        |DATA       |DATA       |NULL
```

### **Solution 2**

*Serialized Object*

---

```
 ID | OBJECT
--------------
 1  | [{ "SERVER_VARIABLES": { "APPL_MD_PATH": "/ROOT/", "APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH": "\\localhost\\" } }]
 2  | [{ "SERVER_VARIABLES": { "APPL_MD_PATH": "/ROOT/", "APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH": "\\localhost\\", "AUTH_TYPE": "DATA", "AUTH_USER": "DATA" } }]
```

With solution 1 each column is data typed correctly and with many nullable columns. With solution 2 it's cleaner and I can record only the columns I am actually using, but requires deserialization when pulled. Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: If you want to be able to query the data, then store it in a normalized form, not serialized in one column. If you never want the ability to quickly write queries analyzing the data set, then go ahead and serialize it. Logging and log analysis are one of the few places where schemaless, non-ACID-compliant document stores like MongoDB are actually appropriate as well. They let you store the minimum amount of information, are very fast in exchange for not caring if you occasionally lose a log entry, and can run reports over the data set with map/reduce.

Comment: What is the expected volume of the data?

Comment: In addition to @Dan Grossman's comment; also if you go with the serialized option, consider using an xml coulmn

Comment: Why, Mitch? I'm so happy the current generation of programmers are leaving the verbose mess that is XML behind whenever possible.

Comment: xml columns have their uses. I'm not advocating their overuse!

Comment: The SQL Server product team use them for extended events, as an example...

Comment: @Edgar Velasquez Lim the volume will be large, I will be using the table to track error, pageview, as well as other custom events based on actions taken on the page. I am leaning toward solution 1, however I was curious as to potential performance benefits of one vs. the other when there are large amounts of data stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with solution 1 since it enables you to search and manipulate pieces of the data easier

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way to track events on a site, is IMHO to use google analytics:
   http://www.google.com/analytics/
   It has already everything to track activities at a very fine grain level.
2. If you want to do everything yourself, probably going for [MongoDB](http://www.google.com/analytics/) will be less painful and probably easier to understand.
3. In the SQL land, I do not recommend serializing so solution 1, especially as you can search through the logs after.

Answer (score 0):

Certain fields can be serialized and certain take a separate columns, it will be the best of breed